# is there any app or workaround to blacklist or whitelist apps and websites?

Tags: software-recommendation, blacklist

I get distracted easily and need something like this.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely! Try [Self-Control](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl/selfcontrol_0.9-1_all.deb), a great application for blocking certain websites and applications for a set period of time.

[image: Self-Control Screenshot]

The best thing about this application is that once you've started it, you can't have a moment of weakness and reverse your decision. Even if you restart your computer, uninstall the application and delete all its files, you will still have to wait until that timer runs out before you can go on Facebook or AskUbuntu again ;).

(It's worth noting that there **IS** a way to turn it off in case of EMERGENCIES ONLY, but I won't tell you it here as that defeats the purpose of the app)

Image and source from: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/self-control-ubuntu/

Comment: Self-Control is the perfect solution for me (ADD). Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not edit /etc/hosts and add an entry pointing your offending websites to your localhost?